# How to access "public can access the community" property using code

Tags: community, community-builder

I'm looking to find a way to access the property "public can access the community" in the communities setting, is that even it exposed using apis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using the [ExperienceBundle API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) using the property "**isAvailableToGuests**"

> "Indicates whether public users have access to the site (true) or not (false). The default value is false.Not supported if the active template for the community doesn't support login (such as Help Center)."

However, this will require the ExperienceBundle API to be enabled. It is set to off by default but can be activated by clicking a checkbox in the [Community settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm)

Comment: @Nick Kahn Did the above solution work for you or do you have any follow-up queries.Thanks